# Fetching list of records based on list of Primary Key using Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I need to fetch multiple records by querying on multiple Primary Keys. For instance, fetching multiple `Employee` records from `Oracle DB`
having fields as `EmployeeId`, `EmployeeName` based on multiple Primary key `employee_id = {1,2,3}` which will result in `3 Employee` records, all within a single `DB` session.

I can do it one by one :

```
Optional<EmployeeBean> eb = employeeRepo.findByEmployeeId(Id);
```

Here `employeeRepo` extends `CrudRepository<Employee, Long>`

Is it possible to do batch wise record fetch with list of Primary Keys in `Spring 5`?

Comment: Do you need something like `select .. from .. where id in (1, 2, 3)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `findByEmployeeIdIn(List<Long> ids)`. [Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords) is a list of keywords you can use with spring data jpa.

Comment: Thanks for the reference link!